# Python socket server that can send different data to multiple clients at the same time

Tags: multithreading, python-3.x, sockets

I'm working on a socket based application in Python 3 that will be used to configure several raspberry pi devices from a central Python server.
I have managed to write a bit of code that allows for multiple devices to connect at the same time but I can only send data from the server on the newest connection.
Here is the code:

```
import socket
import sys
import threading
import time

def manageClient(conn, addr):
    def Ping(conn):
        count = 0
        while True:
            conn.send(str(count).encode())
            time.sleep(1)
            count += 1
            print(count)
    conn.send(b'Welcome to the server. Type something and hit enter\n')
    threading.Thread(target = Ping, args = (conn,)).start()
    while True:
        data = conn.recv(1024)
        print(addr[0] + ': ' + data.decode())
        reply = 'OK...' + data.decode()
        if not data:
            break
        conn.sendall(reply.encode())
    print('Disconnected from ' + addr[0] + ':' + str(addr[1]))
    conn.close()

def addClient():
    host = '192.168.1.24'
    port = 8888

    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    print('Socket created')

    try:
        s.bind((host, port))
    except socket.error as msg:
        print('Bind failed. Error Code : ' + str(msg[0]) + ' Message ' + msg[1])
        sys.exit()
    print('Socket bind complete')
    s.listen(10)
    print('Socket now listening')
    while True:
        conn, addr = s.accept()
        print('Connected with ' + addr[0] + ':' + str(addr[1]))
        threading.Thread(target = manageClient, args = (conn, addr,)).start()
    s.close()

threading.Thread(target = addClient).start()
```

I would like to be able to have multiple users at the same time but a GUI that allows me to configure each device separately over the connection. I understand that this means coming up with a separate name for each connection but I'm not sure how I would achieve this. As of now bi directional communication does work even when multiple devices are connected I'm just unable to send unique messages to each system from the server once a new connection is established.

Thanks

Oliver.

Comment: You've done it, unless `target` isn't a local variable, which it must be.

Comment: Ah, Sorry. I don't think I've quite been clear enough. Multiple clients can already connect but I would like to be able to configure a previous connection once a new one is set up. Would this be done by making instances of the connection instead possibly through a class?